# window.performance.now() is undefined in Safari 9

Tags: javascript, safari, osx-mavericks

I have a problem with `window.performance.now()` in Safari 9. My OS is OS X Mavericks in Macbook Pro Mid 2010.

Apple released Safari 9 for OS X Yosemite and Mavericks users:
http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/30/apple-releases-safari-9-for-yosemite-users/

[caniuse.com/#search=performance](http://caniuse.com/#search=performance) says that in Safari 8 and 9 have support for window.performance.now():

[image]

but I just today updated from Safari 7 to Safari 9 and big disappointment: window.performance is undefined!

[image]

Should it work? Does it work for someone? Is this problem with my OS and/or hardware?

Comment: Works fine for me, Safari 9, Yosemite.

Comment: Does it give fractions? Test eg. here: http://jsbin.com/luxonuv/1/edit?js,output

Comment: It seems that I have to update to El Capitan?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was due to Mavericks. Safari 9 installed well on Mavericks, but for some reason `performance.now()` didn't work.

**May be Apple will fix this bug in the next Safari update.**

I installed El Capitan and it worked:

[image]

Here is my updated test page that uses performance.now() to measure function execution time: http://jsbin.com/qocojaducu/1/edit?js,output.